Google Play Games, Can't get XP for achievements
I implemented Google Play achievements, but when I checked the operation with the internal test version, the XP is displayed as 0 even after unlocking the achievements.
Will XP be 0 if it is an internal test version?
1,Added achievements according to official manual
2,Play the internal test version, unlock achievements and check pop-ups
3,I set XP in Google Play Console, but check that the acquired XP is 0
(Unity2022.3.10f1, GooglePlayGamesPlugin-0.11.01)
